# Has ModalDialog been obsoleted in I.E. 8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, modal-dialog, showmodaldialog

I have an old Asp classic CMS application that powers several websites.  It uses modal dialogs and only works in Internet Explorer.  Now they don't work anymore in IE8.  What is the cause?

Comment: If something only works in IE it should be replaced/rewritten.

Comment: `showModalDialog` works in other browsers. Maybe.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Generally, you're right.  But in the case where the application is a proprietary CMS that was written in ASP classic seven years ago, is not used for new clients, and has the sole function of allowing 10 clients to edit their webpage content, then you are very wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should still work if your users either add your site to the list of trusted sites, or else set Protected Mode to OFF.

They apparently changed the security settings for `showModalDialog` in the interest of conforming to the standards, which is ironic because there is no public standard for `showModalDialog`.